# Angularjs doesn't work for display none style

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to use AngularJS with [Tippy.JS](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) for tooltips.

Tippy's HTML template tooltip ([#creating-html-templates](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/#creating-html-templates)) requires us to use `style="display: none"` for the template, and it handles the rest.

I want to use angularjs features in the tooltip template but failed.
[image]

Here is a fiddle which reproduces the problem. [#fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shank09/h8to34ux/30/)

If you remove `style="display: none"` it works, but Tippy doesn't.

Is there any walkarounds for this?

**Update**
@Razzildinho solution works only to render the value. but it cannot communicate back to the controller. It is one-way data binding, model to tippy.

**Inside Tippy:**

[image]

**Outside:**

[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shank09/h8to34ux/35/)

Comment: What 'AngularJS' features are you trying to implement?

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen Any, in the fiddle and the image u can see that it can't display the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the element id as the html option removes all javascript bindings. To keep them use the DOM element. You should also append within the element that has your controller attached.

```
<!-- Add ID to the controller div -->
<div ng-controller="FrameController as vm" id="controller">
```

You also need to remove the `display: none;` from your template html. From the [documentation](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/#creating-html-templates):

> If you want to clone the template's content into the tooltip, specify the template's id in the html setting. Otherwise use the DOM element itself, which allows you to keep listeners attached. If you use the DOM element choice, ensure it's not hidden with display: none;.

And then your javascript for tippy should be:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('body'), ['app']);
  tippy('.tippy', {
    position: 'bottom',
    animation: 'fade',
    arrow: true,
    interactive: true,
    /* The following 2 lines are new */
    html: document.getElementById('my-template-id'),
    appendTo: document.getElementById('controller')
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixes the problem of the $scope variable being rendered. However, It cannot communicate back to the angularjs code. See: [New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shank09/h8to34ux/35/) and updated question

Comment: @Shank I've updated the answer. You need to use the DOM element rather than the identifier as your `html` option in tippy.

Comment: the Tippy no longer opens. See: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shank09/h8to34ux/36/). Did I miss something?

Comment: You need to remove `display:none;` from the tooltip template

Answer (score 1):

It's because the resulting html and widget is working outside angular scope. The same would happen if you try to implement boostrap widgets and add some angular behavior. That's why boostrap-ui exists, to bridge those two worlds.

The best way to workaround this is by creating directives that link your js pluging with angular. When doing the directive, you might need to recreate the plugin when the expression changes by setting a watcher on vm.message.

See this post as an example: http://bencentra.com/code/2015/09/29/jquery-plugins-angular-directives.html