# Not able to apply a directive to two different controllers in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-templates

[Fiddler link](http://jsfiddle.net/Shank09/vybZy/15/)

I am using [Tippy library](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) to create an HTML tooltip. I made 2 directives to handle the tippy tooltip.

```
.directive('settings', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'tippy-template.html'
    };
  })
  .directive('tippy', function() {
    return function (scope) {
      tippy('.tippy', {
           position: 'bottom',
           animation: 'shift',
           arrow: true,
           interactive: true,
           arrowSize: 'big',
           distance: 20,
           html: document.getElementById('setting-template'),
           appendTo: document.getElementById('settings-controller')
      })
    };
  })
```

The `settings` directive contains the HTML tooltip code and the `tippy` directive will be placed in the HTML tooltip code to get it activated.
The tippy tool shares data with the controller it is in, in this example it shares cache.

Everything works fine if there is only one instance of `tippy` [Fiddler 1 controller](http://jsfiddle.net/Shank09/m2w6seos/1/). I am not able to use the directive again. I was able to recreate the issue I'm having, [Fiddler 2 controllers link](http://jsfiddle.net/Shank09/vybZy/15/).

[image]
From my understanding, `Tippy` can only be used if there is a unique id. Is there a way to solve this?

**tippy-template.html**

```
<div id="setting-template" tippy>
   <ul class="collection">
     <li class="collection-item">
       <div class="col-title"><b>{{title}}</b></div>
       <div class="col-title">Cache</div>
       <div class="col-item">
         <div class="switch">
           <label>Off
                <input ng-model="cache" type="checkbox"><span class="lever"></span> On
           </label>
         </div>
       </div>
     </li>
     <li class="collection-item">
       <div class="col-title"><b>Cache Result</b></div>
       <div class="col-item">{{cache}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Directive usage** (Inside a Controller)

```
<div id="settings-controller" settings></div>
```

Comment: A question n eed to stand our its own, add the tippy-template.html and a sample of your directive's usage. As it stand, the only thing i can say is that you should not have document.getElementById() in your directive.

Comment: @Walfrat Updated (the fiddler contains them both also), Tippy needs to be given an ID to use the template, if not it just outputs the the html on the controller.

Comment: it's not what I see here, you're giving him an HTMLElement, document.getElementById() don't return an Id, it return the HTML Object matching the id. With the directive, you can inject the element object, so you can get the id of the object where the directive was used. Finally, putting an id in a template used multiple time just can't work, since you will end up with multiple id on the html

Comment: oh yes my bad, [Old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700569/angularjs-doesnt-work-for-display-none-style) the reason for using `document.getElementById() `, it was not rendering the scope contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after wreaking my brain on what I was doing wrong, I finally got the solution. You basically need to create a unique IDs for the class (`.tippy`) and I basically used the elements directly, You were saying that `document.getElementById()` is needed for it to work, but `$element[0]` does the same thing. Figured that out by logging both the outputs in the console. Anyway please check the below fiddle with the solution.

<kbd>**`JSFiddle Demo`**</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
  rel="stylesheet">
<body ng-app="myapp">
   <div class="row">
     <!-- CONTROLLER 2-->
     <div class="col s12 m6" ng-controller="controller1">
        <div class="card fill1">
           <div class="card-content">
              <span class="card-title">{{title}}</span>
              <i class="material-icons tippy c-pointer" data-theme="light" data-trigger="click" data-interactive="true" data-animatefill="false" data-arrow="true">settings</i>
              <div id="settings-controller2" parent="tippy" settings></div>
              <div class="filler"></div>
              Cache is : <b>{{cache}}</b>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>

     <!-- CONTROLLER 2-->
     <div class="col s12 m6" ng-controller="controller2">
        <div class="card">
           <div class="card-content">
              <span class="card-title">{{title}}</span>
              <i class="material-icons tippy2 c-pointer" data-theme="light" data-trigger="click" data-interactive="true" data-animatefill="false" data-arrow="true">settings</i>
              <div id="settings-controller" parent="tippy2" settings></div>
                 <div class="filler"></div>
                 Cache is : <b>{{cache}}</b>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="tippy-template.html">
      <div id="setting-template" tippy>
                <ul class="collection">
            <li class="collection-item">
            <div class="col-title"><b>{{title}}</b></div>
            <div class="col-title">Cache</div>
            <div class="col-item">
                <div class="switch">
                <label>Off
                                <input ng-model="cache" type="checkbox"><span class="lever"></span>
                On</label>
              </div>
            </div>
           </li>
           <li class="collection-item">
            <div class="col-title"><b>Cache Result</b></div>
                <div class="col-item">{{cache}}</div>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
    </script>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', [])

.directive('settings', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'tippy-template.html',
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
        $scope.parent = $element;
        $scope.tippyClass = $attrs.parent;
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('tippy', function() {
    return {
      controller: function ($attrs, $scope, $element) {
      console.log($attrs.id);
          tippy('.'+$scope.tippyClass, {
           position: 'bottom',
           animation: 'shift',
           arrow: true,
           interactive: true,
           arrowSize: 'big',
           distance: 20,
           html: $element[0],
           appendTo: $scope.parent[0]
          })
        }
      };
  })
  .controller('controller2', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Controller 2";
    $scope.cache = true;
  })
  .controller('controller1', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Controller 1";
    $scope.cache = false;
  });
```

I recommend you to try to make the directive more generic and easy to use and maybe post a Github GIST so that others will be able to use `Tippy` easily in the future!!!!

Comment: Note : the first element or the tippy function can also be a DOM element.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying to do something like that but failed. so i just made multiple tippys. You saved me :)

Comment: @Shank Improve this code even more and make a GIST, its good for you and others, You're welcome!!!!